# What is a webView exactly?

Tags: ios, webview

I'm setting up a new business app that I want to get some infomation and a page from a website. I don't know how to get a webView to work and I can't find any tutorials that show how to use one. Can someone please show me how to activate a webView?

Comment: What you want, can you explain in more briefly.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=at65EcJ6Inw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView is an object that displays interactive web content, such as for an in-app browser. Implementation steps:

1. First and foremost, In the Storyboard, add WebKit View.
2. In the Viewcontroller.swift file, `import WebKit`.
3. create an @IBOutlet for the webview. (eg: `@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!`) or create webview programmatically.
4. Change the class declaration to implement the WKNavigationDelegate protocol.  (eg: `class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {}`)
5. In the viewDidLoad function, Add :
   `webView.scrollView.bounces = false
   webView.navigationDelegate = self
   let url = URL(string: "https:www.example.com")!
   webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))`
6. following are the useful webview delegates:
   `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {}
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {}`

Full code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
var webView: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!
  webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
  let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
  toolbarItems = [refresh]
  navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
  }
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  title = webView.title 
  }
}
```